# NaN when adding two numbers

Tags: javascript

Why explosion.pdi can be (and is) NaN after adding a number (explosion.ppsd) to it ?

Console logs : (you can see the two are Number and not NaN before the addition, and explosion.pdi is NaN after)

[image: logs from console]

```
console.log('before: pdi = ' + explosion.pdi + ' | ppsd = ' + explosion.ppsd);
console.log('typeof pdi = ' + typeof(explosion.pdi) + ' | typeof ppsd = ' + typeof(explosion.ppsd));

explosion.pdi += explosion.ppsp; // Here :

console.log('after: pdi = ' + explosion.pdi + ' | ppsd = ' + explosion.ppsd);
console.log('typeof pdi = ' + typeof(explosion.pdi) + ' | typeof ppsd = ' + typeof(explosion.ppsd));
```

Edit: Sorry, typo problem (ppsp => ppsd)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have any property such as `ppsp`

```
explosion.pdi += explosion.ppsp   <----
                           ^^^^
```

so you end up with

```
explosion.pdi += undefined   // NaN
```

it should be

```
explosion.pdi += explosion.ppsd
```

Comment: OP  hasn't mentioned the structure of `explosion` object. And if indeed there is no property, shouldn't the question be closed as a typo?

Comment: Thanks haha, It's been 10 minutes that I look for the problem and I did not notice this problem of typo

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in "explosion.pdi += explosion.ppsp;" it needs to be explosion.pdi += explosion.ppsd